# Mysql search with string and number using MATCH() AGAINST() not working

Tags: php, mysql

everything ok?

I'm doing this Query:

```
SELECT model, MATCH (model) AGAINST ('+a3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM models
WHERE MATCH (model) AGAINST ('+a3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance DESC
LIMIT 30
```

But it does not return anything ...

If I just use letters or just ok numbers, but if merge letters with numbers returned nothing.

In my table I have:

A3 1.6 3p

A3 1.8 5p Aut.

and several others.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Consider your min word length SQL setting, also read up on what will be indexed, I am not 100% sure, but I don't think "A3" would be indexed, even with a min word length of 2.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len'`

Comment: For InnoDB, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_token_size'`

Comment: Hello Spencer, thanks for the help.

The table is innodb, following the values of the mentioned variables:

ft_min_word_len = 4
innodb_ft_min_token_size = 3

When searching about the problem, I found some people talking about adjusting these variables, but I do not know if I will have it on the server I have used, I'm not sure if I'll have the autonomy to adjust it, but if I have no alternative, I'll try to adjust.

So is it the case to adjust these variables to what value?

Answer (score 0):

Set ft_min_word_len = 1 in ini file of Mysql.

Then restart Mysql
and repair table 
**REPAIR TABLE test QUICK**